# how to refresh my gridView?

Tags: android, listview, button, refresh

I have a `ListView`. When I click on the button of the row of listview, a button will be created in the `main.xml`, I am having the `onclicklistener` of the button in custom listView adapter. I am saving the click of that button in sqlite and by that sqlite I am updating the gridview adapter.

So my question is when I click on the button, the `GridView` is not updating itself and when I close the application and open it again it gets updated.

I tried using `notifydatasetchanged()` but didn't work..

This is the code in custom List View adapter

```
holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             String text = holder.tvName.getText().toString();
             String image = holder.tvimageurl.getText().toString();
             DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(activity);
             db.addContact(new Contact(text, image));  
             db.close();
```

and this in the main Activity

```
    GridView listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview1);
    imgAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    listView.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
    imgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

ImageAdapter code.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    List<Contact> item;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageAdapter imgAdapter;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private DisplayImageOptions options2;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Contact objBean;
    String getUrl,getId;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    FileOutputStream fos;



    public ImageAdapter(Activity act) {
        this.activity=act;

        inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();


        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(activity);
        item = db.getAllContacts();
        db.close();
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return item.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Contact getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final LinearLayout imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = (LinearLayout)        inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
        } else {
            imageView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add data to ImageAdapter first before calling notifyDataSetChanged. Or recreate it and set again to your GridView

UPD:
Ok, then put loading code to separate method inside your ImageAdapter and call refresh after you add new data

```
public ImageAdapter(Activity act) {
        this.activity=act;

        inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();
        refresh();
}

void refresh()
{
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(activity);
        item = db.getAllContacts();
        db.close();
        notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

But better add new contact manually to your ImageAdapter when you click on your button

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String text = holder.tvName.getText().toString();
    String image = holder.tvimageurl.getText().toString();
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(activity);
    Contact contact = new Contact(text, image)
    db.addContact(contact);  
    db.close();
    imgAdapter.addItem(contact)
    imgAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Comment: i did it in a different adapter the adapter used for gridVIew

Comment: Show us the code of ImageAdapter. Most of all you don't add data to it when you add it to database

Comment: seems that code is truncated. I don't see loading part. Anyway you need to add new data to item field first, and then call notifyDatasetChanged

Comment: before i used to update it directly, but the it was not getting stored, i mean when i close the app it all disappears, thats why i am using sqlite to store the data.

Answer (score 3):

You can force the `Adapter` to update itself within your `onClick` method e.g.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String text = holder.tvName.getText().toString();
    String image = holder.tvimageurl.getText().toString();
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(activity);
    db.addContact(new Contact(text, image));
    db.close();
    notifyDataSetChanged(); // This will do the trick
 }
```

**EDIT**

As you are getting the data when you restart that means it is definitely being saved in the database OK, this suggests that when you invalidate the `Adapter` it isn't reloading the database. Try something like a custom method in `ImageAdapter` like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String text = holder.tvName.getText().toString();
    String image = holder.tvimageurl.getText().toString();
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(activity);
    db.addContact(new Contact(text, image));
    db.close();
    reloadData();  // will refresh the data
    notifyDataSetChanged(); // will update the contents
 }

private void reloadData() {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(activity);
    item = db.getAllContacts();
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: tried that as well but dint work out.. it does work but after i restart my application