# Android update GridView in another activity

Tags: android, gridview

I'm relativly new in the world of Android programming and I ran into some trouble. The problem is that I have defined a gridview in my MainActivity which consists of several imageViews. Those ImageViews have an onClicklistener which opens another Activity with another gridView. When selecting an element (image) in this grid I want to update the gridview in my MainActivity to adopt the selected Element but actually i have no Idea how to implement this.

I found the following code to update the gridView which is working if I try to update my Grid in the same Activity:

```
adapter.notifyDataChanged();
grid.invalidateViews();
grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The onClickListener in my second Activity:

```
mGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

ResolveInfo info = mApps.get(position);

//sets the new drawable
Helper.selectedAppImages[0]=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

//UPDATE THE GRIDVIEW IN MY MAINACTIVITY     

AppView.this.finish() ;
}
});
```

Comment: Refer this may it usefull for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316208/how-to-refresh-my-gridview

Answer (score 1):

In your MainActivity use `startActivityForResult` to display the second Activity passing down data which you need in your second Activity and also override in your MainActivity `onActivityResult`. When selecting an image from your second Activity use `setResult(RESULT_OK, data)` followed by `finish()`. You'll get the result code and data `Intent` in the MainActivity `onActivityResult`.

You can take a look here for more info : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

Second activity:

```
mGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

ResolveInfo info = mApps.get(position);

//sets the new drawable
Helper.selectedAppImages[0]=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

//UPDATE THE GRIDVIEW IN MY MAINACTIVITY     
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
 returnIntent.putExtra("info",info);//<-- or set the image that you want to change
 AppView.this.setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
AppView.this.finish() ;
}
});
```

Start second activity as:

```
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

And in main activity override following function:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (requestCode == 1) {

     if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
         String result=data.getStringExtra("info"); 
         adapter.notifyDataChanged();         

     }
     if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
         //Write your code if there's no result
     }
  }
}//onActivityResult
```